# How to detect if a key physically exists on a keyboard

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, input, keyboard

I am working on a text editor and I use it on both my desktop and laptop. My desktop has some keys that my laptop does not, and they are used in some bindings. I want to be able to do something like this in my config file

```
 if keyDoesNotExist(KEY_HOME) then
     bind(bla, bla, bla)
 end
```

So is it possible to detect if keys are present on the current keyboard?

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646296(v=vs.85).aspx) looks like it might have what I'm looking for. It mentions returning the device handle to the physical keyboard layout but does not elaborate further.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this reliably. Keyboards don't seem to identify themselves with any great deal of precision; e.g. when you plug a new keyboard into a Mac it actually asks you to identify the keyboard yourself (by pressing certain keys in relation to other keys).

Comment: What negative effect are you trying to prevent? Binding an action to a non-existent key doesn't appear to do much harm.

Answer (score 0):

You can query for a [KEYBOARD_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntddkbd/ns-ntddkbd-keyboard_extended_attributes) like this:

```cpp
    KEYBOARD_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES extended_attributes{ KEYBOARD_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES_STRUCT_VERSION_1 };
    DWORD len = 0;

    if (!DeviceIoControl(interfaceHandle.get(), IOCTL_KEYBOARD_QUERY_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES, nullptr, 0, &extended_attributes, sizeof(extended_attributes), &len, nullptr))
        return false;

    FormFactor = extended_attributes.FormFactor;
    KeyType = extended_attributes.IETFLanguageTagIndex;
    PhysicalLayout = extended_attributes.PhysicalLayout;
    VendorSpecificPhysicalLayout = extended_attributes.VendorSpecificPhysicalLayout;
    IETFLanguageTagIndex = extended_attributes.IETFLanguageTagIndex;
    ImplementedInputAssistControls = extended_attributes.ImplementedInputAssistControls;
```

Keyboard Form Factor

- 0: Unknown Form Factor
- 1: Full‐Size keyboard
- 2: Compact keyboard. Such keyboards are less than 13” wide.

Keyboard Key Type

- 0: Unknown Key Type
- 1: Full‐travel keys
- 2: Low‐travel keys such as those on laptop keyboards.
- 3: Zero‐travel or virtual keys

Keyboard Physical Layout:

- 0: Unknown Layout
- 1: 101 (e.g., US)
- 2: 103 (Korea)
- 3: 102 (e.g., German)
- 4: 104 (e.g., ABNT Brazil)
- 5: 106 (DOS/V Japan)
- 6: Vendor‐specific – If specified, 0x02C4 must also be specified.

The bad news is that modern `KEYBOARD_EXTENDED_ATTRIBUTES` approach will work only for a small number of keyboards on the market - since this stuff was added relatively recently in the HID spec (see [Review Request 42:  Consumer Page Keyboard Assist Controls](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/hutrr42c_0.pdf)) and not many keyboard vendors have it implemented in hardware. So your request will just fail for many keyboards.

There is [KEYBOARD_ATTRIBUTES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntddkbd/ns-ntddkbd-keyboard_attributes) exist which have `NumberOfKeysTotal` and `NumberOfFunctionKeys` fields. But information from `KEYBOARD_ATTRIBUTES` seems not reliable at all and just returns same info fro "generic 101-key keyboard" for any HID keyboard...

PS: [RID_DEVICE_INFO_KEYBOARD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-rid_device_info_keyboard) have the same info as `KEYBOARD_ATTRIBUTES` and can be requested by a call to [GetRawInputDeviceInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getrawinputdeviceinfow).